# Node.js asynchronously handling http requests

Tags: express

I am new to Node.js, trying to learn it and I am stacked with my problem.
The problem is following. I am trying to build a simple project (using Express) with page, which will display user list, which is stored in MongoDB.

Here is my router:

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var userRepository = require('../repositories/user_repository.js');

router.get('/:long?', function(req, res) {
    var long = req.param('long');
    long = !!long;
    userRepository.getAllUsers(function(users) {
        res.render('index', {
            users: users
        });
    }, long);
});

module.exports = router;
```

Let me explain the idea.
Here is the handler for http://mywebsite.com/ url, which can also have an optional parameter (http://mywebsite.com/?long=something). This paremeter is casted to the boolean type and passed to tge getAllUsersMethod of userRepository.

Here is my userRepository:

```
var db = require('../context').db;

var userRepository = {
    getAllUsers: function(callback, long) {
        var now = Date.now();
        var then = now + 5000;
        if (long) {
             while (Date.now() < then) {}
        }
        db.users.find({}, function(err, users) {
            callback(users);
        });
    }
};

module.exports = userRepository;
```

getAllUsers() function's logic depends on the 'long' argument. If it's false, it just takes user list form my database. If long = true, it `sleeps` for 5 seconds an only then extract data from database.

When I am entering URL: http://mywebsite.com/ then long = false and I see my user list immediately.

When I am entering URL: http://mywebsite.com/?long=something then long = true and page is loading ~5 seconds as expected.

Then I am trying to do the following. I am entering: http://mywebsite.com/?long=something and right after that, in another tab entering: http://mywebsite.com/. First tab loads 5 seconds as expected, but the problem is that the second tab waits also 5 seconds until the first tab is loaded and only then loads. That means, that requests are handled not asynchronously. With this 'sleep' I am trying to simulate situation, when database request will take a lot of time to be handled.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

> With this 'sleep' I am trying to simulate situation, when database request will take a lot of time to be handled.
>
> What am I doing wrong?

Don't `sleep`.  That's what you're doing wrong.

Your JavaScript runs in a single thread.  If you block a thread by sleeping, Node.js cannot continue.  If you want to simulate an asynchronous action that takes time, use `setTimeout` with the callback instead.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. But query to database theoreticaly can take a lot of time also. If JavaScript runs in a single thread, it will block thread also. Or I am getting something wrong?

What is the difference between my sleep implementation and a very big query?

Comment: @DmitryPapka Most of your very large query will be occurring on the database server, and not in the JavaScript library in your application.  Your application sends the query off to the database server and moves on to other things until it starts getting data back.  This operation does not block, but sleep does.  In addition, native extensions (like much of what is built into Node.js) can have their own thread pool and do whatever they want.  The only time you're stuck in that single thread is when in the JavaScript side of things.  (Or in a native extension that doesn't use its own threading.)